# XQuery doesn't update XML data

Tags: sql-server, update, xml, xquery

I am trying to run the script to update an XML column:

```
UPDATE DataImpTable
SET serviceData.modify('replace value of (/SMObjInfo/CentralData/SMData/CentralSDItem/ControlData/text())[1] with "9876"')
WHERE identifier=5
```

```xml
<SMObjInfo xmlns="DataService/1.0.0.0" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CentralData>
    <SMData>
      <CentralSDItem>
        <ControlData>1234</ControlData>
      </CentralSDItem>
    </SMData>
  </CentralData>
</SMObjInfo>
```

Change value of `ControlData` to 9876 but the value doesn't seem to change in the XML for the `/SMObjInfo/CentralData/SMData/CentralSDItem/ControlData` value.

Is it anything to do with typed and untyped XML?

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to declare the namespaces in the `modify` function.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<SMObjInfo xmlns="DataService/1.0.0.0" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CentralData>
    <SMData>
      <CentralSDItem>
        <ControlData>1234</ControlData>
      </CentralSDItem>
    </SMData>
  </CentralData>
</SMObjInfo>';
SET @xml.modify('
    declare default element namespace "DataService/1.0.0.0";
    replace value of (/SMObjInfo/CentralData/SMData/CentralSDItem/ControlData/text())[1]
    with "6789"
    ');
PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @xml);
```

In your original xml fragment, you have declared the following namespace that is never used:

`xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

If your actual xml documents do make use of this namespace, and you want to modify those elements, you'd need to add the following declaration into the `@xml.modify` function:

`declare namespace i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";`

Results (formatted for readability):

```
<SMObjInfo xmlns="DataService/1.0.0.0" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CentralData>
        <SMData>
            <CentralSDItem>
                <ControlData>6789</ControlData>
            </CentralSDItem>
        </SMData>
    </CentralData>
</SMObjInfo>
```

I wrote a blog post about the modify function, along with some more examples at [SQLServerScience.com](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/t-sql/xml/modifying-xml-values/?utm_source=dba.stackexchange.com&utm_campaign=238013&utm_medium=referral)

Answer (score 10):

If you have the XML in table you should use UPDATE instead of SET and there you can put the namespace declaration outside the XML_DML expression using [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-2017).

```
with xmlnamespaces(default 'DataService/1.0.0.0')
update DataImpTable
set serviceData.modify('replace value of (/SMObjInfo/CentralData/SMData/CentralSDItem
                                            /ControlData/text())[1] with "9876"')
where identifier=5
```